# Auto complete command-line arguments based on command and subcommand in tcsh

Tags: autocomplete, tcsh

I am using tcsh shell and trying to setup autocomplete for a wrapper script written in perl. The usage of the script is similar to how SVN works and looks something like this:

`command first_argument -option1 option_argument option2 option2_argument ...`

The valid choices for *option* depend on *first_argument* and corresponding *arguments* can be file names or a custom list depending on the *-option* provided.
Is it possible to configure the *complete* command to look at *"command first_argument"* instead of *command*?

If possible, I would like to avoid writing a full blown argument handler to do this, since the option list is long. I have tried using single quotes as well as double quotes to say something like `complete "command first_argument" 'completion options'`, but that does not seem to work. Please help.

Best Regards,

Abhishek